# Node values in Boltzmann machines (0/1 vs -1/1). Are they the same?

Tags: mathematics, graphical-model

Boltzmann machines were introduced by Hinton and Sejnowski as taking values in $\{0,1\}$. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_machine) entry also uses this convention. However, [Hopfield Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfield_network), which are the deterministic version of Boltzmann machines, are usually introduced as taking values in $\{-1,1\}$. Ising models also follow this convention.

With the energy function being defined equivalently in both models as
$$ E(x) = \sum_i b_ix_i + \sum_{i<j}w_{ij}x_ix_j$$
it seems that the two conventions would behave differently. For example, how would the $\{0,1\}$ model learn a preference for checkered patterns?

---

More generally, in an undirected graphical model where the nodes take values in $\{a,b\}$, we can define the interaction (energy) between two neighbouring nodes $x$ and $y$ as
$$E(x,y) = \begin{cases}
      w_{aa}, & \text{if}\ x=a,y=a \\
      w_{ab}, & \text{if}\ x=a,y=b \\
      w_{ba}, & \text{if}\ x=b,y=a \\
      w_{bb}, & \text{if}\ x=b,y=b
    \end{cases}$$
or equivalently represented by the matrix
$
\begin{bmatrix}
    w_{aa}       & w_{ab}  \\
    w_{ba}       & w_{bb} 
\end{bmatrix}
$.

Boltzmann machines restrain the interactions between two neighbouring nodes to being described by a single scalar $w_{ij}$. In the case when our values $\{a,b\}$ are $\{0,1\}$, we get
$$ E(x_i,x_j) =
\begin{bmatrix}
    w_{ij}       & 0  \\
    0       & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If we set $\{a,b\}$ to $\{1,-1\}$, we instead get
$$ E(x_i,x_j) =
\begin{bmatrix}
    w_{ij}       & -w_{ij}  \\
    -w_{ij}       & w_{ij} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Are these two formalisms really equivalent? It seems unlikely...